# Create an alias to a function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to create an alias to `CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL_MESSAGE(string message, T expected, T actual)`. I tried:

```
template<class T> void (&_assert)(string, T, T) = &CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL_MESSAGE;
```

Not sure if its right at all, but I am getting errors like

```
Error   1   error C2530: '_assert' : references must be initialized h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\test\testqueryevaluator\testgetcandidatelist.h   22
Error   2   error C2998: 'void (__cdecl &__cdecl _assert)(std::string,T,T)' : cannot be a template definition   h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\test\testqueryevaluator\testgetcandidatelist.h   22
```

Whats the right syntax?

Comment: Are you sure `CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL_MESSAGE` is a function not a *macro*?

Comment: I am not sure actually ... how do I know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a forwarding function:

```
template<class T> 
inline void _assert(const string& message, T expected, T actual) 
{ CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL_MESSAGE(message, expected, actual); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple put, there is no right syntax, because, as phoeagon noted, that is a macro, no function:

[See the reference](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/1.8.0/group___assertions.html#a1)

Answer (score 1):

`CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL_MESSAGE` is a macro and not a function, and so you can either "wrap" it with an actual definition of an `inline` function (as a previous answer suggested) or simply `#define` an alias macro:

```
#define _assert CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL_MESSAGE
```

Of the two, I would choose the wrapper function method so it could be declared in a namespace and to avoid naming conflicts.